# How to transform many array to 1 standard?

Tags: php

i have many api service with response

```
[
    'brand_name' => Adidas,
    'item_count' => 24
]
```

and

```
[
    'brand_name' => Nike,
    'count_item' => 254
]
```

and

```
[
    'name' => Reebok,
    'count_all' => 342
]
```

how to transform it to 1 standard? oop please

```
['brand' => $value, 'cnt' = $count]
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking and you haven't shown us what you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the same order, just combine your keys with the values:

```
$array = array_combine(['brand', 'cnt'], array_values($array));
```

If not, just match and replace:

```
$array = array_combine(
    preg_replace(['/.*name.*/', '/.*count.*/'], ['brand', 'cnt'], array_keys($array)),
    $array);
```

If it could be `brand`, `name` or `brand_name`, etc. Then use an OR `|`:

```
/.*(name|brand).*/
```

If you know all of the possible combinations, then:

```
$replace = ['brand_name' => 'brand', 'name' => 'brand',
            'item_count' => 'cnt', 'count_item' => 'cnt', 'count_all' => 'cnt'];

$array = array_combine(str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, array_keys($array)),
                       $array);
```

One of these should get you on the right path.

Comment: i dont know possible combinations

Comment: OK, that was 1 of 3 options. If there is no common word and they are not in the same order then it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To transform many array into one standard like above, you need to think of common criteria that can apply to all arrays. In your case, I can see that all arrays have 2 keys, with the first keys contain a word "name" so I can use it as a criterion for "brand". Then there is second keys contain a word "count" used as a criterion for "cnt".

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $item) {
    $brand = '';
    $cnt = '';
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($key, 'name') !== false) {
            $brand = $value;
        }
        elseif(strpos($key, 'count') !== false) {
             $cnt = $value;
        }

        // more conditions
    }
    $new_array[] = ['brand' => $brand, 'cnt' => $cnt];
}
```

Suppose you have another array:

```
[
    'brand' => 'Danbo', 
    'total' => 200,
]
```

Since this is an exception, you need to make another condition:

```
elseif(strpos($key, 'brand') !== false) {
    $brand = $value;
}
elseif(strpos($key, 'total') !== false) {
    $cnt = $value;
}
```

or append to existing conditions:

```
if(strpos($key, 'name') !== false || strpos($key, 'brand') !== false) {
    $brand = $value;
}
elseif(strpos($key, 'count') !== false || strpos($key, 'total') !== false) {
    $cnt = $value;
}
```